# PowerShell download script not working

Tags: powershell, download

I made a basic PowerShell script. To download files from 2 urls

However even though it seems to download the files my computer can't open them.
When I mean my computer can't open the files here are the 2 specific errors:
When I try to open the first file I get the error: This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package. When I try to open the second file it just says "This app can't run on your PC"

Here is the script:

```
$storageDir = $PSScriptRoot
$storageDir = $pwd
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$url = "http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=20914"
$file = "$storageDir\xnafx40_redist.msi"
$webclient.DownloadFile($url,$file)
$url = "http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=17851"
$file = "$storageDir\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe"
$webclient.DownloadFile($url,$file)
```

Comment: Define "can't open them". What happens when you try?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers When I try to open the first file I get the error: This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package. When I try to open the second file it just says "This app can't run on your PC"

Comment: You're downloading the confirmation (HTML) pages instead of the installers (try opening the files in an editor). The actual links to the files you want to download are in those pages.